# Who wants to start? - I do vs I want to

Tags: sentence-construction

If I ask a group of people:

> Who wants to start a conversation?

should someone say - I want to or I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to answer the question "Who wants to start ..?"

> I do
>
> I will
>
> I would
>
> I want to
>
> I'd like to
>
> Can I?
>
> Might I?
>
> If I may?

and so on.  All of these are correct, and all mean more or less the same thing.  They do express varying degrees of *politeness* ("I would" is slightly more polite than "I will", as is any option that asks permission), but otherwise the *certainty* or *uncertainty* of each varies based on things like context, intonation, and body language.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context, if you ask a bunch of kids they may say (jumping up and down screaming)

> I do! I do! Me! Me! Pick me!

however, as an adult, one may say (in a more subdued tone with *added connotation*)

> I do.
>   I will *(start the conversation if no one else is brave enough to)*
>   I would like to *(start the conversation)*
>   I am willing to *(stick my neck out and look like an idiot starting this conversation)*

An adult may use "I do" but more often will be more eloquent than a child when taking on the responsibility of starting a group conversation.

Comment: +1 For Me! Me! Pick me! - that's definitely from the Shrek movie.